# Display graphics inside the Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to augment an existing VS addin with some graphical capabilities. For example, I might want to draw lines between related definitions.

So I'd like to overlay my own WPF control on top of the one used by the editor. How do I get hold of the WPF control used by the editor?

Comment: that sounds like an interesting addin. Is it (going to be) public ?

Comment: @Gos: No. I quit that contract.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new adornment layer for your graphics. See [Inside the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.ASPX#adornments) for more details.